# Meaning of "you can tap in the delay time" (manual of Behringer DR 400)?

Tags: effects-pedal, delay

What is the meaning of the next text in manual of Behringer DR 400?

> When pressing the foot switch for 2 seconds or longer, you can tap in the delay time

[Link to manual](http://www.fullcompass.com/common/files/22440-BehringerDigitalReverbDelayDR400UserManual.pdf)

There are three general groups of pedal functions:

- delay
- delay + reverb
- reverb

There are two knobs that change their functionality **according to the mode**, but not according to the **"tap in the delay time"**.

Does anyone know what long pressing actually does?

Comment: Are you asking what the "tap" function does? Or do you know what that is and you're saying it doesn't seem to work the way the manual suggests? In case you meant the first, many delay effects have a "tap tempo" feature where you can tap a button at a particular tempo to set the delay time. You could press it a bunch of times as if you're tapping along with the beat, but you only really need to press it twice. The time between the last two taps is how long the delay will be. This is especially useful when playing live if you need differing delay times set on the fly and hands-free.

Comment: @user37496 , I don't know how it works. I'll receive pedal in the middle of may, and I'd like to know how to deal with it. Everything else is clear for exception of "tapping in the delay time". Thanks for comment I'll try this

Answer (score 2):

Sounds to me that holding for two seconds will activate another mode were you get to select the amount of delay by taping the button with your foot.

Hold the pedal for 2 seconds and the ON/BATT LED flashes, then tap the pedal a few more times in rhythm to set the delay time.

That is my guess based on the manual which is not very good.